# jQuery show next content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a website which always returns a random phrase after refresh. I want to make this thing without refreshing the page. This is the code:

```
  $(window).click(function() {
    $('.ats p').fadeIn(500);
  });
```

".ats p" is a div class, it fades in after I click anywhere in the site, but the problem is when I click one more time that phrase doesn't change; nothing happens.

How do I make it refresh code every time I click? It should be like this: when I click, the phrase shows, and when I click second time, then it should show the next phrase.

Comment: From where do you obtain the phrases?

Comment: Yeah, at first the phrase should fade in and then second time when you click it then should fade in other phrase.

Comment: I obtain everything from database

Comment: Yeah it fades in content which is in .ats p That's good. I need to change the text when I click second time.

Comment: @user3134037: have you heard of AJAX? In your click handler, you need to initiate an AJAX request to the server to get a phrase and then populate the phrase text into your page. After that you can have it fade in. What's your server side technology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    // ajax request that will pull your phrases from your database
    // for each phrase in the array, push it to the javascript phrases array
});

var phrase = 0;
var phrases = ["Phrase 1", "Phrase 2", "Phrase 3"];

$(window).click(function() {
    $('.ats p').fadeIn(500);
    $('.ats p').html(phrases[phrase]);
    phrase++;
});
```

How's that? Just populate your `phrases` array on page load with data from your database. Then on each click increment a variable that can be used to fetch the next phrase.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try... it will fade out, update the phrase, then fade back in.

```
  $(window).click(function () {
      $.ajax({
          url: "path/to/randomPhrase.php", 
          //change the above to whatever is generating the random phrase
      }).done(function (text) {
          $ats = $('.ats p');
          $ats.fadeOut(500, function () {
              $ats.text(text);
              $ats.fadeIn(500);
          });
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Without Ajax, see it live: http://jsfiddle.net/sh641gz4/2/

### html

```
<div class="ats">
    <p class="active">1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
    <p>2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
    <p>3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
    <p>4 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
    <p>5 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
    <p>6 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.</p>
</div>
```

### css

```
.ats {
    position: relative;
}
.ats > p {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
    transition: all .3s ease-out;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ats > p.active {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

### js

```
    $('.ats > p').on('click', function(){
        var nextP  = $('.active').removeClass('active').next();
        if (!nextP.length)
            nextP = $('.ats > p').first().addClass('active');
        else
            nextP.addClass('active');
    });
```